# How to grant photos permission for flutter integration test in iOS simlulator?

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator, flutter-test, user-permissions

Please help to identify the problem about permission to access photo library in iOS simulator (iOS 15.0) with flutter test (integration_test).

I'm trying to use flutter integration testing with a mobile app required permission to access photo. ex change user profile picture.

try to use command line as below to grant the permission

`xcrun simctl privacy booted grant photos  <app bundle id>`

But when return to access photos in the app,it always asks permission to access photos library. (xcrun for grant all access is not working)

Anyway, when using revoke

`xcrun simctl privacy booted revoke photos  <app bundle id>`

For this time, the app displays no permission to access photos library correctly. (xcrun is working as expected)

How to grant permission to access photo library,no permission asking when runing flutter test script?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the following keys to your **Info.plist** file located in */ios/Runner/*?

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Grant permission to photo library</string>
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have. The app shows description as specified with NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription correctly. But I don't want it shows pop-up to ask permission after grant permission with xcrun. :P